# Padding on input element not working as expected on mobile safari (iphone)

Tags: iphone, css, mobile-safari

Why doesn't padding work properly in iphone safari? Padding-right to be exact

Simple Html:

```
<div class="content">
   <input  class="inputsBlock"/>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.content{
    padding:18px;
}

.inputsBlock{
    width:100%;
    border:2px solid #000;
}
```

It works in anothers browsers. Any solution?
Image:

[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8uaelyyrkmm8lin/Captura.JPG)

Comment: Could you post a screenshot or something? we can't really help with such question if we don't have more information.

Comment: Tested in safari and it [works](http://jsfiddle.net/LKhtM/).

Comment: try adding `padding: 18px !important;`

Comment: Works for me in Safari too.

Comment: try it In Iphone Safari?

Comment: I have uploaded an image

Comment: @C-Link, with `!important` doesn't work

Comment: Try to use a [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to remove the browsers _default_ styles.

Comment: @Vucko, I use normalize.css

Comment: do you have demo or online....

Comment: safari may be taking as display inline from any code try giving display: block; to your .content

Comment: @C-Link, The same result. I haven't added a demo because it only doesn't work in Iphone safari

Comment: @KeesSonnema, I've upload an image

Comment: Just try display: inline-block;

Comment: @KeesSonnema, I obtain the same result

Comment: Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LKhtM/2/

Comment: @KeesSonnema. The same problem. Surprisingly, the right padding is not so null, but neither is complete

Comment: Hm, yes I noticed that. there´s padding, but not on every side.

Comment: It's a problem for me because I have to put `widht="100%"` then I can't put margin `.inputsBlock`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, just remove padding

```
.inputsBlock{
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LKhtM/9

tested on simulator only